# slideDown on scroll and slideUp when inactive

Tags: jquery

I have a fixed menu which contains the header and the menu, on scroll down the menu disappears and then reappears when the user stops scrolling.

I also have a background image which I am animating the background-position-y. The issue that I am having is that the menu disappears and reappears fine but the background image animates to -70px but doesn't animate back to 0px when the menu appears.

I have made a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pwLquf3h/4/).

Here is the stripped code from the site:-

**HTML**

```
<body>
  <div id="header-wrapper">

    <div id="branding-wrapper">

    </div>
    <a href="#!">
      <div id="inone-wrapper"></div>
    </a>
    <div id="navbar-wrapper">

    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function($) { 
    var $menu = $("#navbar-wrapper");
    var opacity = $menu.css("opacity");
    var scrollStopped; 

var fadeInCallback = function() {
      if (typeof scrollStopped != 'undefined') {
        clearInterval(scrollStopped);
      }
      scrollStopped = setTimeout(function() {
        $menu.slideDown({
          duration: 300,
          easing: 'linear'
        });
        $('#inone-wrapper').animate({
          'background-position-y': '0'
        });
        $('#branding-wrapper').css('background', 'rgba(255,255,255,1)');
      }, 800);
    }

    $(window).scroll(function() {
      if (!$menu.is(":animated") && opacity == 1 && $(window).scrollTop() > 130 && $('#navbar').not('.in') && ($(window).width() >= 992)) {
        $menu.slideUp({
          duration: 300,
          easing: 'linear',
          complete: fadeInCallback
        });
        setTimeout(function() {
          $('#inone-wrapper').animate({
            'background-position-y': '-70px'
          });
        }, 200);
        $('#branding-wrapper').css('background', 'rgba(255,255,255,0.9)');
      } else {
        fadeInCallback.call(this);
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: @DaniP - I've updated the JSFIDDLE and it's working now, the placeholder image is the issue, how it animates the background size to -72px to doesn't do it back to 0px when the menu appears again

Comment: It does, it just takes a while... you need to change your timing

Comment: Doesn't ever come back for me, well at least not in Chrome @Adjit

Comment: It does, it takes like 10 seconds... but I think that is because you are telling it to animate the background position up and down in the same call... for your slide up you call `fadeInCallback` which drops the menu down, but right after that you call `setTimeout` to raise it back up...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is coming from the animation queue filling up. So what happens is it takes time for jQuery to catch up with itself. You're `#inone-wrapper` is where things are being held up - it keeps animating the background position to `-70px` repeatedly, so if you include the following you should be ok:

```
$('#inone-wrapper').stop(true, true).animate({ });
```

Since you are using a `.scroll()` event, there are a lot of scroll events, so the functions are being called very rapidly. What you need to do, is before you start your animations you need to clear the animation queue as well as complete the previous animation using jQuery's `.stop()` function and passing it `true, true`. The defaults of the `.stop()` are `false, false`

> `.stop( [clearQueue ] [, jumpToEnd ] )`
>   https://api.jquery.com/stop/

Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/pwLquf3h/7/

```
$(document).ready(function($) { 
    var $menu = $("#navbar-wrapper");
    var opacity = $menu.css("opacity");
    var scrollStopped; 

var fadeInCallback = function() {
      if (typeof scrollStopped != 'undefined') {
        clearInterval(scrollStopped);
      }
      scrollStopped = setTimeout(function() {
        $menu.slideDown({
          duration: 300,
          easing: 'linear'
        });
        $('#inone-wrapper').animate({
          'background-position-y': '0'
        });
        $('#branding-wrapper').css('background', 'rgba(255,255,255,1)');
      }, 800);
    }

    $(window).scroll(function() {
      if (!$menu.is(":animated") && opacity == 1 && $(window).scrollTop() > 130) {
        $menu.slideUp({
          duration: 300,
          easing: 'linear',
          complete: fadeInCallback
        });
        setTimeout(function() {
          $('#inone-wrapper').stop(true, true).animate({
            'background-position-y': '-70px'
          });
        }, 200);
        $('#branding-wrapper').css('background', 'rgba(255,255,255,0.9)');
      } else {
        fadeInCallback.call(this);
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: Awesome explanation and works perfectly, thank you very much!

Comment: is there a way to prevent the menu from sliding up if you are within a certain distance from the top, I tried to do this with `$(window).scrollTop() > 130` but this doesn't seem to do the trick (so when your at the top the menu doesn't slide down, or if you scroll to the top, the navbar is already back to it's normal state before you reach the top)

Comment: @nsilva that is working, if you increase that to lets say `500` you will see a difference.